# Select records where stored date at least x days older than current date

Tags: mysql

I have a table where a date is stored as a string: 
(date_letter_mailed e.g. 3-15-2016)

I need to retrieve records where the stored date (date_letter_mailed) is more than 3 days older the current date.

Using the code shown, no records are retrieved.

```
SELECT * FROM rec_new_license 
WHERE 
date_letter_mailed >= (DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m-%d-%Y') + 3 DAY)
```

Also tried:

```
STR_TO_DATE(date_letter_mailed,'%m-%d-%Y' ) <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

Comment: I have tested your second predicate and it works fine on my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `STR_TO_DATE`

```
SELECT * FROM rec_new_license 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date_letter_mailed, '%c-%e-%Y') < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks :)